# Comparar ArrayList's distintos en Java

Tags: java, arraylist, bucle-for

Buenas noches me gustaría que me ayuden en los siguiente:

Tengo 2 ArrayList's:

```
ArrayList<Persona> listaPersona;
```

que su contenido transformandolo en Json es el siguiente:

```
[{"nombre":"Luis", "edad":"22"},{"nombre":"Juan","edad":"24"},
  "nombre":"Jose","edad":"15"}]
```

Ahora, tengo otro ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> nombres=new ArrayList(); 
nombres.add("Luis");
nombres.add("Juan");
```

Como podría hacer para eliminar de mi "listaPersona" toda la fila que no contenga el nombre de mi ArrayList "nombres" ?

Me gustaría que mi `ArrayList<Persona>` quede de la siguiente manera:

```
[{"nombre":"Jose","edad":"15"}]
```

He intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int i=0; i<listaPersona.size(); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<nombres.size(); j++) {
        if(!listaPersona.get(i).getNombre().equals(nombres.get(j))) {

            listaPersona.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero no es la forma correcta ya que en la primera iteracion, se compara Luis con Juan y al no ser iguales se elimina la fila, y eso es lo que no quiero, agradeceria mucho su ayuda! Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que todo, lo que dices que quieres:

> Como podría hacer para eliminar de mi "listaPersona" toda la fila que
>   no contenga el nombre de mi ArrayList "nombres" ?

No es lo mismo a lo que esperas como resultado:

> Me gustaría que mi ArrayList quede de la siguiente manera:
>
> [{"nombre":"Jose","edad":"15"}]

Independientemente de lo que realmente quieras, si conservar las personas que estan en el listado de nombres o eliminar las que estan en ese listado. Se resuelve de la misma forma.

Para lograr lo que quieres tienes que realizar 2 busquedas secuenciales tal y como lo estas haciendo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaPersona.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nombres.size(); j++) {
        //persona en indice i esta en listado de nombres?
    }
}
```

Pero esa pregunta, no se responde en una sola iteracion de `j`, sino que en todo ese bucle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaPersona.size(); i++) {
    //persona en indice i esta en listado de nombres?
    boolean estaEnNombres = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < nombres.size(); j++) {
        if (listaPersona.get(i).getNombre().equals(nombres.get(j))) {
            estaEnNombres = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (estaEnNombres) {
        listaPersona.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, lo que realizas lo puedes reescribir aprovechando el API de `List`, como el metodo `contains`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaPersona.size(); i++) {
    boolean estaEnNombres = nombres.contains(listaPersona.get(i).getNombre());

    if (estaEnNombres) {
        listaPersona.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

O incluso mas corto, usando `removeIf`:

```
listaPersona.removeIf((p) -> nombres.contains(p.getNombre()));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió tu segunda respuesta, solo tuve que negar  el if, ya que deseo que se elimine si es que no esta en nombres ( if(!estaEnNombres)){....} . Gracias nuevamente!

Answer (score 2):

Considerando la siguiente clase Persona.

```
public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private String edad;

    public Persona(String nombre, String edad) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    public void setEdad(String edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persona [nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + "]";
    }
}
```

Creamos la clase Test para probar lo pedido.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Persona> listaPersona = new ArrayList<>();
        listaPersona.add(new Persona("Luis","22"));
        listaPersona.add(new Persona("Juan","24"));
        listaPersona.add(new Persona("Jose","15"));

        List<String> nombres = new ArrayList<>(); 
        nombres.add("Luis");
        nombres.add("Juan");

        for(String nombre: nombres){
            listaPersona.removeIf(p -> p.getNombre().equals(nombre));
        }

        System.out.println(listaPersona);
    }
}
```

Obtenemos como resultado.

```
[Persona [nombre=Jose, edad=15]]
```

**Explicación**

Para recorrer nuestra lista **nombres** usamos un for-each, dentro de cada iteración verificamos si el **nombre**(variable local en la iteración) coincide con algún nombre de **Persona** dentro de nuestra lista **listaPersona**; si este es el caso utilizamos el método removeIf(Introducido en Java 8).
El método removeIf acepta una lambda(Predicate en nuestro caso), de ser true la comparación de Strings(**p.getNombre().equals(nombre)**) la **Persona** es removida de nuestra lista **listaPersona**.

Comment: Tu respuesta es diferente al resto (para mi gusto mejor incluso) pero quedaría bien que explicases un poco lo que has hecho. La consulta Linq principalmente

Comment: Hecho.Saludos..

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema que estás teniendo es porque, como tu mismo dices, "al no ser iguales se elimina la fila" y lo que quieres es lo contrario. Pues está de más la negación (!) en el `if`.

```
if(!listaPersona.get(i).getNombre().equals(nombres.get(j)))
```

El otro problema es que te sobra el `i--` que utilizas cuando eliminas. Esto provoca que cuando elimines un elemento de la lista, en la próxima iteración del `for` anidado, se analice, una vez más, el elemento anterior al que eliminas. Por ejemplo, si tenemos esta colección [1, 5, 3], y eliminamos el elemento de la posición 1 (el 5), el siguiente tomaría su lugar y por ende estaría ubicado en la misma posición (la 1): [1, 3]. Así que en la siguiente iteración, tenemos que volver a analizar la misma posición desde donde eliminamos. Peor aún, en el caso de que se elimine el de la posición 0, en la siguiente iteración tendríamos un `IndexOutOfBoundsException` ya que la `i` será `-1`.

La solución correcta sería esta

```
for(int i=0; i<listaPersona.size(); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<nombres.size(); j++) {
        if(listaPersona.get(i).getNombre().equals(nombres.get(j))) {
            listaPersona.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

> NOTA: Te faltaba en el código que compartiste el paréntesis que cierra el primer `for`. Pero imagino que haya sido un error al transcribir el código, porque de otro modo tendrías errores de compilación.

No obstante, a no ser que te obliguen a recorrer las colecciones manualmente, te comparto una mejor solución utilizando un iterador (`Iterator`) y el método `contains()` de la clase `String`.

```
Iterator<Persona> iter = listaPersona.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (nombres.contains(iter.next().getNombre())) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: una acotacion, el problema que mencionas al realizar `i--` no existe como tal, justamente al realizar `i--` el OP esta dejando sin efecto el `i++` al final del bucle, volviendo analizar en la misma posicion eliminada.

Comment: Analiza bien el problema y luego me dices. Si te fijas bien, el `i--` se realiza dentro del segundo `for` por lo que si `i` vale 0 y se elimina un elemento, en la siguiente iteración del sefundo `for`, `i` será -1. Creo que si hubieses probado el código del OP, no escribes este comentario.

Comment: Bah, tienes razón. Pero eso solo ocurre porque sigue ejecutando ese bucle a pesar de encontrar lo que buscaba